# Catching the button click event in other application

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to catch the click event of the button which is clicked on Windows Form Application lets say in **Application A** and I want to catch it in **Application B** which is also a Windows Form Application.

I have created both the Applications and added the button in Application A. Now when the button is clicked in Application A, I want to catch the event in Application B.

Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen for events in another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878/listen-for-events-in-another-application)

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a "quick" way to share .NET events between different processes. 
You need to catch the event in the same application which raised it, implement an inter-process communication mechanism (WCF, socket, ...) between Application A and application B and use it to send the event data from A to B.

See this question and related answers for more details: [Listen for events in another application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17878/11317043)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) or a **WH_MOUSE_LL** hook
(P/Invoke)

(tested on Windows 10, with VS 2015)

(also [IUIAutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationeventhandler) but more complicated)

Comment: Available in .Net: [Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.addautomationeventhandler). It can be added to a Form/Window, specifying the whole SubTree of descendants elements, along with an event type.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain you, how you may catch the Button Click event a little bit otherwise.

You can create the instance of your 2nd Form in your first one or in a reachable Class, then calling a Public Method in your 2nd Form or in your class, which does what you want.

Example Form 1:

```
var _secondForm = new Form2();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _secondForm.Open();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MethodInSecondForm()
}
```

and your Second Form:

```
public void MethodInSecondForm()
{
    // Event here
}
```

You can create this instance in a Class, too and make it easier.